# C# Find nodes with given attribute names in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a big XML document. A snippet of it is shown below:

```
<AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=]]>

<StreamsetInfoRecord>
  <StreamsetName>
    http://localhost/abc/abc08.osdinfra.net-88/abc/abc.partner/shares/abcAdmin/jobRepository/cooked/jobFileExts/2018/10/09/JobMetaData_20181009.ss
  </StreamsetName>
  <StreamsetInfoList>
    <StreamsetInfo 
        StreamId="859e1a91-bb17-46f6-94f4-79d67c1f7e83" 
        abcName="abc://abc08-dorp-co3c/vol61/system/jobRepository/cooked/jobFileExts/2018/10/09/JobMetaData_20181009.ss" 
        VcName="http://localhost/abc/abc08.osdinfra.net-88/abc/abc.partner/shares/abcAdmin/jobRepository/cooked/jobFileExts/2018/10/09/JobMetaData_20181009.ss" 
        Length="16132378830" 
        Count="3002" 
        CreationTime="10/10/2018 3:53:36 AM" 
        ExpirationTime="4/8/2019 3:53:36 AM" 
        ModificationTime="10/10/2018 3:12:02 AM" />
  </StreamsetInfoList>
</StreamsetInfoRecord>
```

Now from this document I want to only retrieve tags which have word Length= in them. i.e. from the above example snippet I want to retrieve the following information:

```
StreamsetInfo 
  StreamId="859e1a91-bb17-46f6-94f4-79d67c1f7e83" 
  abcName="abc://abc08-dorp-co3c/vol61/system/jobRepository/cooked/jobFileExts/2018/10/09/JobMetaData_20181009.ss" 
  VcName="http://localhost/abc/abc08.osdinfra.net-88/abc/abc.partner/shares/abcAdmin/jobRepository/cooked/jobFileExts/2018/10/09/JobMetaData_20181009.ss" 
  Length="16132378830" 
  Count="3002" 
  CreationTime="10/10/2018 3:53:36 AM" 
  ExpirationTime="4/8/2019 3:53:36 AM" 
  ModificationTime="10/10/2018 3:12:02 AM"
```

It is possible to retrieve just this information from XML. I know I can extract XML node from attribute using:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("...")
```

But in the above SelectNodes requires me to specify the exact XPath expression. However in my document I only know that the tag of interest to me contains an attribute with name "Length" I dont know its exact XML path.

Is it possible to do this type of Regex search in XML in C#

Comment: XPath _can_ specify filter by attribute regardless of tagname. [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx):  `*[@specialty]` - All elements with the specialty attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("//StreamsetInfo[@Length]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> lengthElements = doc.Descendants("StreamsetInfo").Where(x => x.Attribute("Length") != null).ToList();

            var results = lengthElements.Select(x => new {
                streamId = (string)x.Attribute("StreamId"),
                abcName = (string)x.Attribute("abcName"),
                vcName = (string)x.Attribute("VcName"),
                length = (long)x.Attribute("Length"),
                count = (int)x.Attribute("Count"),
                creationTime = (DateTime)x.Attribute("CreationTime"),
                expirationTime = (DateTime)x.Attribute("ExpirationTime"),
                modificationTime = (DateTime)x.Attribute("ModificationTime")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```